# What Is The Derivative Of f(x^3)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find the derivative of $f'(x^3)$. I tried using chain rule and I got $3x^2f'(x^3)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Do you mean "I want to find the derivative of $f(x^{3})$"?

Comment: Perfectly correct, if what you mean is $\bigl(f(x^3)\bigr)'$.

Comment: do you want the derivative of $f(x^3)$ or $f'(x^3)$? If its the first one then yes, you have correctly applied the chain rule. If you want the second, then it should be $3x^2f''(x^3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function is $g(x)=f'(x^3)$, then it would be by the chain rule $g'(x)=f''(x^3)3x^2$.

Otherwise, if you meant $f(x^3)$, it would be $f'(x)3x^2$.